# Please help me fix my messages

Tags: iphone, messages

I have an iPhone 5c, when I send iMessages my contact receives them as coming from my email address. I went to Settings to change this but my phone number is greyed out and my email address is in black. It will not let me change it to my phone number.
I can't find the "Start new conversations from" section.

Comment: I tap on the email address but it does not change. There is not a "start new conversation"

Comment: No there is not a start a new conversation 

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the relevant settings

Answer (score 3):

[image]Go to Settings->Messages->Send & Receive and then tap your phone number under "Start New Conversations From". Your phone number should not be greyed out here, you were probably just looking at the "You Can Be Reached By iMessage At" section.

Comment: Sorry, I meant tap your phone number. But, I don't get why there is no "Start New Conversations From" section.

Comment: Do you see the "Start New Conversations From" section at the bottom of the screen? (This image was doctored to censor my personal info for privacy reasons)